# Posting a form (ajax) within FancyBox2

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm attempting to post a form from FoncyBox2 and have so far had no luck. The result of the following code is a closed overlay. Nothing else happens. No error. No nothing. All I want is for the result (which is in this case the content of the field) to appear in place of the form in the same overlay.

HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="formPage.php">Open Overlay</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".fancybox").fancybox();

            $("#question-form").bind("submit", function() {
                $.fancybox.showActivity();

                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    cache : false,
                    url: "formProcessing.php",
                    data: $(this).serializeArray(),
                    success:function(data){
                        $.fancybox(data);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Form (formPage.php):

```
<form id="question-form" action="" method="POST">
Name <input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Form processing (formProcessing.php):

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Oh, I'm not worried about validation. I'm planning to do that another way.

Thanks,
@rrfive

Comment: Your problem seems to be here **data: $(this).serializeArray();** try to add form selector like this: **data: $('#question-form').serialize()**

Comment: Strange that you didn't have any errors .... anyway, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/11299547/1055987 (includes demo)

Comment: possible duplicate of [FancyBox v2 - login box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296373/fancybox-v2-login-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I managed to solve the problem. It turns out I'm a dumb-ass and it was a simple case of moving the code $.ajax code to the form page. Here my final code.

HTML (index.html) - unchanged:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="formPage.php">Open Overlay</a>
```

JavaScript (index.html):

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

Form (formPage.php) - unchanged:

```
<form id="question-form" action="" method="POST">
Name <input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

JavaScript (formPage.php):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#question-form").bind("submit", function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    cache : false,
                    url: "formProcessing.php",
                    data: $(this).serializeArray(),
                    success:function(data){
                        $.fancybox(data);
                    }
                });
                return false;
});
});
```

Form processing (formProcessing.php):

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Thanks to @JFK and @Daniel for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

i am new user in this community.
First all sorry for my bad english :)

I also use the above code, it work perfectly but i would like the document to be reloaded after the fancybox close.

I tried with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // cart iframe
        $("#stocart").bind("submit", function() {
            $.ajax({
                type        : "POST",
                cache       : false,
                url         : "reloadpage.php",
                data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
                success: function(data) {$.fancybox(data);},
                afterClose: location.reload()   
            });
            return false;   
        });
    });
</script>
```

but this reload a page without display the fancybox... how reload page when i click fancybox close button?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Then, get to know [what the community is about](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting...