# submitting contact form in fancy box

Tags: jquery, fancybox, form-submit, contacts

I've got a contact form opening in a FancyBox 2 modal window. But when you submit the form, current page got refreshed and contact form gets disappeared.

You can check this bug in [my site](http://magichome.doubledot.in/) by clicking **support** in main menu

Here's my code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

and this is my contact form link,

```
<a href="formhome.php" class="menu-support fancybox.ajax">Support</a>
```

Can anyone tell me how to submit my contact form in fancy box without reloading the page please?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/11299547/1055987 if that helps

Answer (score 0):

what you need here is [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**jquery**

```
$('#idOfcontactForm').submit(function(){
   $.ajax({
     url:"yourpage.php", // action of the form ,
     data:$(#contactform).serialize(), // send forms data to server
     dataType:"json", // take response as json
     type:"post", //send form by post or get
     success:function(result){
       alert(result.msg);
    }
   });
    return false;  // default submit return false
 });
```

**PHP(yourpage.php)**

```
  //manupulate you submited data..
  // if using post you can get data by $_POST;
  echo json_encode(array('msg'=>"successfully saved");
```