# Powermail form in fancybox (ajax submit)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox, typo3

can powermail the form send by ajax? or I can say a normal form, using jQuery, that he will send the form via ajax and does not reload the page. 
I'd like to open a form in a fancybox and send it. but I find no solution: (

Comment: You can send the form via ajax, just bind a `submit` event to the form's selector using `.bind()` or `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+) to `preventDefault()`, then process the form inside the callback function of the `.on()` method. Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/11299547/1055987

Comment: thank you, I already know. the problem is that I want to send the form not its own script but that should typo3 take over for me.