# How do I reload fancybox iframe form with errors in Flask

Tags: jquery, python, iframe, flask, fancybox

In Flask have an iframe display a login form with fancybox and it works fine, but if there is an error I want to reload the form. The problem is when I submit the form with errors, it loads another iframe inside the current iframe. How do I load the form in the current iframe.

```
@user.route('/signin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signin():
    """ Login a user
    """
    form = SigninForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        username = form.username.data
        password = form.password.data

        if username:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get( username = username )
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                form.username.errors = ['No such user or password']
                context = {'form':form}
                return render_template('sign-in.html', **context )

        else:
            form.username.errors = ['Enter a Username or Email address']
            context = {'form':form}
            return render_template('sign-in.html', **context )

        if user.check_password(password):
            login_user(user)
            return render_template( 'close-iframe.html' )
        else:
            form.username.errors = ['No such user or password']
            context = {'form':form}
            return render_template('sign-in.html', **context )
```

Here is the Jinja2 template

```
  {% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}

{% block body_block %}
<body>

    <div class="header">
        <div class="wrapper">
                    <div id="sign-in-show"">
                        <div class="signin-form">
                            <div class="sign-up-in-tabcont" style="display: block;">
                                <form id="sign-in-form">
                                    {{ form.csrf_token }}
                                    <div class="form-single-row">
                                        {{ render_field(form.username, id="email") }} 
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-single-row">
                                        {{ render_field( form.password, id="password") }}
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-single-row">
                                        {{ render_field( form.submit, value='Login') }}
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-single-row">
                                        <p class="forget-password">
                                            <a href="{{url_for('user.forgot')}}">Forgot Password?</a>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="header-outer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
{% endblock %}
```

here is the javascript I have in the main application. It works, except that I cannot change the html in the iframe when it returns

```
function send_ajax(e){
    $.ajax({ type : "POST",
        cache : false,
        url: "/signin",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success:function(data)
        {   
            var box = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('html');
            box.html(data);
        }
     });

    return false;       
}

$("#sign-in-form").bind( "submit", send_ajax ); 
$('.fancybox').fancybox({ onClose: function(){ window.location.reload() } });
```

and the html that activates it is

```
<a class="fancybox_signin" id="sign-in" href="{{url_for('user.signin')}}">Sign In</a>
```

Comment: Can you post your JavaScript code where there is the fancybox call? Have you tried with `target="_self"` or `target="_parent"` to the form?

Comment: The problem is that you are calling another fancybox on your success function I guess, and you are opening a fancybox with the result of an ajax calling and you have an iframe type fancybox open.
Can you try to simply update the content of the iframe in your success function using `location.reload();` instead of `$.fancybox(data);`?

Comment: I tried that and it only reloaded the original. I also tried doing this $('body',$('.fancybox-iframe').contents()).html(data); to see if it would change the html inside the box, but it didn't

Comment: I need to discuss with you in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of experiments I finally figured it out.

```
function send_ajax(e){
    $.ajax({ type : "POST",
        cache : false,
        url: "/signin",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success:function(data)
        {   
            parent.jQuery.fancybox(data);
        }
    });

    return false;       
}

$("#sign-in-form").on( "submit", send_ajax );
```

There is only one problem with this. If you enter the wrong password twice, the second window does not appear.